# Setting Entity Framework Connection String at Runtime Throws "Keyword Not Supported"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to set my connection string in my Entity Framework at runtime. In an attempt to do this, I have the following code:

```
string connectionString = "tcp:[serverName],[port];initial catalog=[databaseName];user id=[userName];password=[pwd];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
using (MyEntities entities = new MyEntities(connectionString))
{
  MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
  // Set entity properties here

  entities.MyEntities.Add(entity);
  entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I get to the line that says `entities.MyEntities.Add(entity)`, an exception is thrown. That exception has the following information:

```
Type: ArgumentException
Message: Keyword not supported: 'tcp:[serverName],[port];initial catalog'.
```

Why won't the code that I've written work? For the life of me, I can't figure it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing "Server":

`string connectionString = "Server=tcp:[serverName],[port];initial catalog=[databaseName];user id=[userName];password=[pwd];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";`

(Assuming you are just substituting [serverName], [port], [databaseName] into the code in your question to hide the sensitive details. Obviously [serverName] isn't a valid hostname.)

I'm not 100% sure that "Server" and "Initial Catalog" work together, so you may need "Data Source" instead of "Server", or "Database" instead of "Initial Catalog".